# How to read a C struct from a binary file in Rust?

Tags: serialization, io, rust

I have read [How to read a struct from file in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410028/how-to-read-a-struct-from-file-in-rust), but `std::slice::raw::mut_buf_as_slice` has been deprecated, hence I want to re-ask this question.

I want to read a `struct utmp` from `/var/run/utmp`, and I have tried the following code:

```
fn read_utmp() -> Utmp {
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(File::open("/var/run/utmp").unwrap());
    let mut ut = vec![];
    let size = mem::size_of::<Utmp>();
    reader.take(size as u64).read_to_end(&mut ut);
    unsafe {
        std::mem::transmute(ut)
    }
}
```

And as expected, the compiler complaint:

> error: transmute called with differently sized types: std::vec::Vec (192 bits) to Utmp (3056 bits) [E0512]

How could I do this?

Comment: The question you referenced has now been updated.

Comment: *but `std::slice::raw::mut_buf_as_slice` has been deprecated, hence I want to re-ask this question* — in the future, it may be more productive to ask what the replacement for the deprecated functionality is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that `raw::mut_buf_as_slice` was replaced with [`slice::from_raw_parts_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts_mut.html).

---

**Note** that the following code does not take into account any [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) or [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding) issues and is intended to be used with [POD types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure). `struct utmp` should be safe in this case.

---

Here is a function that can read a struct (of a pod type) from a file:

```
use std::io::{self, BufReader, Read};
use std::fs::{self, File};
use std::path::Path;
use std::slice;

fn read_struct<T, R: Read>(mut read: R) -> io::Result<T> {
    let num_bytes = ::std::mem::size_of::<T>();
    unsafe {
        let mut s = ::std::mem::uninitialized();
        let mut buffer = slice::from_raw_parts_mut(&mut s as *mut T as *mut u8, num_bytes);
        match read.read_exact(buffer) {
            Ok(()) => Ok(s),
            Err(e) => {
                ::std::mem::forget(s);
                Err(e)
            }
        }
    }
}

// use
// read_struct::<Utmp>(reader)
```

If you want to read all utmp structs from the utmp file, you can execute `read_struct` multiple times or read all the file at once:

```
fn read_structs<T, P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> io::Result<Vec<T>> {
    let path = path.as_ref();
    let struct_size = ::std::mem::size_of::<T>();
    let num_bytes = try!(fs::metadata(path)).len() as usize;
    let num_structs = num_bytes / struct_size;
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(try!(File::open(path)));
    let mut r = Vec::<T>::with_capacity(num_structs);
    unsafe {
        let mut buffer = slice::from_raw_parts_mut(r.as_mut_ptr() as *mut u8, num_bytes);
        try!(reader.read_exact(buffer));
        r.set_len(num_structs);
    }
    Ok(r)
}

// use
// read_structs::<Utmp, _>("/var/run/utmp"))
```

Comment: The original question has now been updated. I'd encourage you to post this answer there as it's a great compliment to the existing answer.

Comment: is there really no safe way to read a binary file in rust into a struct?

Comment: You can use `serde` and `bincode` to handle binary files in a safe manner.